# distinguish in information_schema DB: column with default NULL vs. column with no DEFAULT

Tags: mysql

i use mysql 5.7.
if i look only into 'information_schema' database, is there a way to distinguish a column with default NULL and a column without default?

here's my table:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE defaults (default_null varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, no_default varchar(100)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE defaults ALTER COLUMN no_default DROP DEFAULT;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE defaults;
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table    | Create Table                                                                                                                             |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| defaults | CREATE TABLE `defaults` (
  `default_null` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `no_default` varchar(100)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO defaults SET no_default = 'foo';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO defaults SET default_null = 'bar';
ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'no_default' doesn't have a default value
mysql>
```

*no_default* and *default_null* columns are different, but in information_schema.columns table they are the same:

```
mysql> SELECT column_name, is_nullable, IFNULL(column_default, 'real NULL') FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'defaults';
+--------------+-------------+-------------------------------------+
| column_name  | is_nullable | IFNULL(column_default, 'real NULL') |
+--------------+-------------+-------------------------------------+
| default_null | YES         | real NULL                           |
| no_default   | YES         | real NULL                           |
+--------------+-------------+-------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Does it even make any difference. if you insert a new row with no data both show NULL. so if Insert defaults values (NULL,NULL); results in the same, they are the same

Comment: @nbk, if i insert a new row without 'no_default', i get an ERROR.

Comment: maybe relevant: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13341?focusedCommentId=99353&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour has every Version if strict sql mode is enabled.

> If strict SQL mode is enabled, an INSERT statement generates an error if it does not specify an explicit value for every column that has no default value. See Section 5.1.10, “Server SQL Modes”.

You can find it under https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html